# How to reverse/swap the order of “Sales price” and “Regular prcie” in woocommerce?

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

By default wooCommerce displays price as "Regular price" first and "Sale price" second. I wish to reverse the order for all types (simple,variation,...).  Is this possible?  How?

Thx

Answer (score 1):

You're going to want to use [hooks and filters](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/hook-docs.html) to change that.  I would look at the `woocommerce_get_price_html` and/or `woocommerce_variable_price_html` filters.

EDIT:

here is the core WC code you need to alter:

```
/**
 * Format a sale price for display.
 *
 * @since  3.0.0
 * @param  string $regular_price Regular price.
 * @param  string $sale_price    Sale price.
 * @return string
 */
function wc_format_sale_price( $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    $price = '<del>' . ( is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price ) . '</del> <ins>' . ( is_numeric( $sale_price ) ? wc_price( $sale_price ) : $sale_price ) . '</ins>';
    return apply_filters( 'woocommerce_format_sale_price', $price, $regular_price, $sale_price );
}
```

as you can see, there's a filter on the returned value.  what you want ot do is hook into that filter and return the prices how you want.  something like this:

```
add_filter('woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'wc_override_sale_price_format', 10, 2);
function wc_override_sale_price_format( $regular_price, $sale_price ) {
    $price = '<ins>' . ( is_numeric( $sale_price ) ? wc_price( $sale_price ) : $sale_price ) . '</ins> <del>' . ( is_numeric( $regular_price ) ? wc_price( $regular_price ) : $regular_price ) . '</del>';
    return $price;
}
```

Comment: I did this, but the $product->get_regular_price() is retuning 0 for variable products.

Comment: @Benmay I mocked something up for you.  Modify as you need

Comment: This doesn't work any more. Could anyone update it?

Comment: As in flagman's answer, wc_override_sale_price_format should take 3 arguments: it needs an extra old value parameter first.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a snippet, which works fine for me:

```php
//Swap "Regular price" and "Sale price"
function swap_sale_regular_price($price, $regular_price, $sale_price)
{
    $price = '<ins>' . (is_numeric($sale_price) ? wc_price($sale_price) : $sale_price) . '</ins><del aria-hidden="true">' . (is_numeric($regular_price) ? wc_price($regular_price) : $regular_price) . '</del>';
    return $price;
}
add_filter('woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'swap_sale_regular_price', 10, 3);
```

For this code to work the declared function `swap_sale_regular_price` have to accept as arguments all variables inside of it `swap_sale_regular_price($price, $regular_price, $sale_price)`.
Also in `add_filter` we have to to notice, that our function accepts three argument `add_filter('woocommerce_format_sale_price', 'swap_sale_regular_price', 10, 3)`.

Comment: I agree this looks more correct than MrBen's answer, but please can you explain how you fixed that (else people might think it's a duplicate at first glance)

Comment: It looks like duplicate, but there are some difference. I added `$price` into function as first  argument, and forth argument of `add_filter` must be 3, because now function is accepting three arguments.

Comment: Add the details to your answer though... ...sometimes people won't parse through the comments.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).